# The complete invariance property

Tags: general-topology, fixed-points

Let $(X,d)$ a bounded metric space. We say that $X$ has the complete invariance property (shortly, the CIP) if for each non-empty and closed $A\subset X$ there is a continuous $f:X\rightarrow X$ such that $A$ is the set of fixed points of $X$.

Assume that there is a sequence of compact subsets of $X$, put $K_{n}$, such that $d_{H}(K_{n},X)\leq 1/n$ (here, $d_{H}$ is the Hausdorff metric) and $K_{n}$ has the CIP. Under these conditions, Has $X$ the CIP?

Many thanks in advance for yur comments or suggestions.

Comment: I'm not sure, but here's something to try if the answer is yes: given $A \subset X$, set $A_n = X \cap K_n$.  Let $f_n:K_n \to K_n$ have fixed point set $A_n$.  Given a point $x \in X$, choose a point $y_n \in K_n$ such that $d(x,y_n) < 1/n$.  (Such a point exists because $X$ is contained in the $1/n$ neighborhood of $K_n$.)  Define $f(x)$ to be the limit of $f_n(y_n)$.  There are many details to check (well-defined, existence of limit, no additional fixed points).  But if this approach doesn't work, I'd look for a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks Robert Bell. Yes, I haved tried your approach but I can not to given a formal proof (as you say, f is well-defined, etc). Moreover, assuming X is compact, I do not see clear the proof....